# How to get minutes from overlapping time frames

Tags: c#

I have a curious problem. I can easily solve this by hand, but can't quite figure out how to code it. My problem involves timezones. I have an app that does work during a set time of day. The data it works on is timezone specific data. I want to calculate the overall "width" of the processing window in minutes.

Say that they pane is from 9:00am to noon. The pane is 180 minutes wide. I have data for timezones -4, -5, -6, -7 and -10. Since the pane is wider that the offset, I calculate the "width" of the processing window as 9 x 60 or 360 mins.

I'm writing this in C#. I have some code whipped up to start working on this problem, but I'm not sure how to represent the inputs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you need `TimeSpan` and `DateTimeOffset`, though I don't entirely understand your description.

Comment: What's a pane and whats an offset?

Comment: The pane is just a time period. 09:00 to 12:00 for example. The offset is the timezone offset. For example, -5 from GMT is central time.

Comment: I whipped up some C#-ish pseudo-code. However, I don't know how useful this value would really be. I can imagine that if the data is distributed non-evenly, the result may be misleading:

`s = 0;
e = 0;
width = 0;

for (int x = 1; x < windows.Count; x++)
{
 if (windows[x - 1].End >= windows[x].Start && windows[x - 1].End <= windows[x].End)
 {
  e = x;
 }
 else
 {
  e = x - 1;
  width += windows[e].End.Subtract(windows[s].Start).TotalMinutes;
  s = x;
 }
}

width += windows[e].End.Subtract(windows[s].Start).TotalMinutes;

return width;`

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx

Comment: That kind of looks like overkill for what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the link, though. It might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is take the beginning of the earliest time, and the end of the latest time and use `DateTimeOffset` to get the difference. Something like this:

```
//1/1/2011 9:00 AM -4
var earliest = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-4, 0, 0));
//1/1/2011 12:00 PM -10
var latest = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-10, 0, 0));
Console.Out.WriteLine("minutes = {0}", (latest - earliest).TotalMinutes);
```

This yields a result of 540. 180 minutes of time between the two, plus an additional 360 minutes for the timezone difference. 360 is the difference between -4 and -10 timezones if the hours were exactly the same. If that wasn't what you're looking for, please update your question to add more details / scenarios.

Comment: The only gotcha I have to watch for is if there isn't any work in say the Pacific time zone or if the pane gets narrowed. Then, you have to account for the gap.